# How to include js files in AngularJs directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to load js files in my directive. I have some problems with tinyMCE 4 and rails assets in prod. tinymce.js needs theme.js and so I can't compile both of them. I want to call those js files only when I need the directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can have a directive, which, before rendering, checks to some global thingy whether the script has already been loaded, and if not, you put the source script in your directive's template. If there are timing or rendering issues, you can do it with a nested approach or something like that, but meh...not really sure if it is worth the hacking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the same approach as I use in https://github.com/dotJEM/angular-code-directives/blob/master/src/script.ts which is a very basic script loader service.

```
/// <reference path="_references.d.ts" />

interface IScriptService {
    (url:string);
}

angular.module('dotjem.directives.code').service('$script', [<any>
    function ():IScriptService {
        var loaded = {};
        return function (url:string) {
            if (!(url in loaded)) {
                $.ajax(url, {
                    dataType: "script",
                    success: () => {
                        loaded[url] = url;
                    },
                    async: false,
                    cache: true
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```